# Redirecting users to the form and popping out an error message

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to PHP. How do I redirect the user to the form and pop an error message out when they fail to fill all the text fields?

Here's my code:

```
<div class = 'register'>
        <form action = "registration.php" method="post">
            <p>Name:<br> <input type="text" name="name"></p>
            <p>Student No:<br>  <input type="number" name="studentNo"></p>
            <input type="submit" onclick="load()" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
</div>
<br>
<?php   
        if(isset($_POST['name']) && (isset($_POST['studentNo']))){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $studentNo = $_POST['studentNo'];
            echo "Name: ".$name."<br>";
            echo "Student No:".$studentNo."<br>";
        }
        else{

        }
?>
```

Comment: One way would be to set a session variable when you find an error, use the `header("Location: myform.php")` to redirect the user back to the form drawing code, and have the form code check to see if the session variable is set, and if it is, display the error. You can have multiple session vars or an array if you want multiple error messages.

Comment: What about using the HTML5 require attribute? You don 't need a session. In the error case you can redirect to the form php file with a get parameter, that indecates, what is wrong.

Comment: thank you guys!!! you helped me all so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using up to date techniques of 2020?

## The Form

You can validate a html form directly on the client side to minimize occuring errors. For this purpose just use the html5 constraint validation api.

```
<form id="my-form" action="registration.php" method="post">
    <label>
        Username
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" required>
    </label>
    <label>
        Number
        <input type="number" name="number" value="" required min="1" max="9999" step="1">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

As you can see the input elements got different type attributes. For example purposes I 've not taken your name und studend number elements. The first input element is the username and therefore we use a text input element. This element can take every input.
The second input element is a number type. Here you can enter number values only.
Both elements have the required attribute. Without filling in anything you can not submit the form. You have to enter a username and a number.

## Server side validation with PHP

Since we have the client side validation you have to validate the received data on the server again. Never trust any user input! Retrieving data on the server just means, that the user has filled something in. It is not cler, if the input is that, what you expect.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $valid = true;
    $errorType = '';
    
    if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !strlen(trim($_POST['username'])) { 
        $valid = false;
        $errorType = 'username';
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['number']) || !intval($_POST['number'])) {
        $valid = false;
        $errorType = 'number';
    }

    if (!$valid) {
        header('registration.php?error=' . $errorType);
        exit();
    }
}
```

The above shown code checks if the submit button was hit. If so both input elements are checked, if they are not empfy. You can add more validation here. In case of the username a minimum string length is practicable. The number can be checked against database content, if the number exists in the database.

## Displaying error in html

Since we have defined a GET parameter `error` in our redirect with the php header function, we can use this in our markup.

```
<form id="my-form" action="registration.php" method="post">
    <label>
        Username
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" required>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] === 'username') :?>
            <p>Yo! We need your username, dude!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <label>
        Number
        <input type="number" name="number" value="" required min="1" max="9999" step="1">
        <?php if (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] === 'number') :?>
            <p>Yeah ... entering a number is not that hard.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

## Alternatives

There are any. You can use JavaScript to catch the errors the HTML5 Constraint Validation API throws, when you use the required attributes within your form elements. The api shows you what error occured and you can show more specific error messages on what error occured.

Another alternative can be AJAX. If the Constraint Validation API ends up with a valid result, send the input data with an asnychronous javascript request. This way the page is not reloaded on any occuring error on the server side. The user stays on the website and will be redirected on success.

But before you use this advanced techniques, learn how to use a simple html form with php. ;)

Comment: Thanks Marcel! I learned a lot from you, really appreciate your help!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Name is required")';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "yourpage.php"';
        echo '</script>';
        }
    if (empty($_POST['studentNo'])) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Student name is required")';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = "yourpage.php"';
        echo '</script>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's good that you made an effort and provided the code but it will be even better if you provide at least a bit of explanation of it along with it, at least give a overview of what is your code about, for a better understandings from user's point of view

Comment: thanks Frog Bid for helping me!!! this also gave me another option!!